# random array of objects with no repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, random

I use splice to show quotes with no repeat but I think I miss something cause `q.length` is'not change

this is my code:

```
async function JsonFile(){

    const response = await fetch('/quotes.json');
    const data = await response.json();

    const quotes = data.quotes; 
    getQuotes(quotes)
}

let backupArray =[];

function getQuotes(q){

    const random = Math.floor(Math.random()* q.length);

    name.textContent = q[random].name;
    quote.textContent = q[random].quote;
   const spliceEl = q.splice(random,1);
   console.log(spliceEl);
   backupArray.push(spliceEl);
   console.log(q.length);
   console.log(backupArray)
  

}

button.addEventListener('click' ,JsonFile)
```

Answer (score -1):

What Am I assuming is that you want to get "N" number of quotes with no repetition

```js
const quotes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
const N = 4;

const getRandomQuotes = (q, n) => {
  const result = [];
  const check = {};
  let cntr = n;

  let randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * q.length);

  while (cntr > 0) {
    if (!check[randIndex]) {
      result.push(q[randIndex]);
      check[randIndex] = true;
      cntr--;
    }
         
    randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * q.length);
 
  }
  
  return result;
}


const selectedQuotes = getRandomQuotes(quotes, N)

console.log(selectedQuotes);
```